# DOMPDF Multiple Documents Generated In One PDF

Tags: dompdf

I am using DOMPDF to generate invoices.
1 invoice at time is perfect.

But i want to print (from a while) all invoices between date
all is perfect
But Dompdf print only the last invoice.

The dompdf code

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$date1 = "2008-01-01";
$date2 = "2009-01-01";
$user = "User_1"; 

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoices  WHERE datum BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' AND user='$user' ORDER BY nummer ");
while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$num=$rows[number];
$datum=$rows[data];
$pay=$rows[pay];

// Need to get the user info from other table
$Query2 = "SELECT * from user WHERE user='$user'";
while ($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($Result2))
{
$name = $rows2[name];
//ETC...

// Now we generate the html invoice
$html =
    '<html><body>'.
//the invoice html
    '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
}
}
$dompdf->stream("Invoice.pdf");
```

I want to get all invoices ( sometimes 5, sometimes 50 ) in 1 pdf file.
How to ?

I close my whiles at end of files, but don't help.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written right now you render your first document then don't do anything with it. So the second pass through the while loop will overwrite the first pass. There are a few ways to achieve what you want, but the easiest would be to compile all your HTML into a single document then render that.

Using your code as a start:

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$date1 = "2008-01-01";
$date2 = "2009-01-01";
$user = "User_1"; 
$invoices = array();

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoices  WHERE datum BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' AND user='$user' ORDER BY nummer ");
while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $num=$rows[number];
  $datum=$rows[data];
  $pay=$rows[pay];

  // Need to get the user info from other table
  $Query2 = "SELECT * from user WHERE user='$user'";
  while ($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($Result2)) {
    $name = $rows2[name];
    //ETC...

    // Force page break between invoices
    if ( strlen( $html ) > 0 ) { $html .= '<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>'; }

    // Now we generate the html invoice
    $invoices[] = '<!-- the html invoice -->';
  }
}

$html = '<html><body>' . implode( '<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>' , $invoices ) . '</body></html>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("Invoice.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks. i have try , but get 1 blank page now.

Comment: what do you get if you echo out the contents of the `$html` variable?